# Linear transformation and vector space over field F

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am currently self studying abstract algebra and am reading in Modules over PID in foote and dummit, and I am confused on one paragraph:

"For example, suppose V is a vector space of dimension n over F and we choose a basis for V. Then giving a linear transformation $T$ of $V$ to itself is the same thing as giving an $n*n$ matrix $A$ with coefficients in $F$(and choosing a different basis for V gives a different matrix B for T which is similar to A i.e. is of the form $P^{-1}AP$ for some invertible matrix P which defines the change of basis)." ( page 457, foote and summit)

I have a hard time understanding this statement, especially the linear transformation and choose basis part. I would greatly appreciate some explanation and maybe some examples. Thank you.

Comment: have you taken a linear algebra course?

Comment: Sadly, I don't have a good linear algebra background :(

Comment: Here is a good linear algebra text: Linear Algebra Done Right, Authors: Axler, Sheldon

Answer (score 1):

A basis for a vector space $V$ is a minimal generating (or *spanning*) set. Vector spaces ($F$-modules, for $F$ a field, which is certainly also a ring) have the "nice" property that the cardinality of such a set is an invariant property of the space $V$. This invariant is called the *dimension* of $V$ (analogous to the *rank* of a free module).

Choosing a basis allows us to uniquely determine the coefficients of elements of $V$ as $F$-linear combinations of the basis. So, for example, if our basis is $B = \{v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n\}$, we can write any $v \in V$ uniquely as:

$\alpha_1v_1 +\alpha_2v_2 + \cdots +\alpha_nv_n$

for some $a_j \in F$,

in which case we say the $n$-tuple $(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\dots,\alpha_n)$ is the "coordinate vector" of $v$ in the basis $B$.

For a *linear* transformation $T:V \to V$ (this is the vector space version of $F$-module endomorphism, that is an $F$-module homomorphism $V \to V$), we can write:

$T(v) = T(\alpha_1v_1 +\alpha_2v_2 + \cdots +\alpha_nv_n) = \alpha_1T(v_1) +\alpha_2T(v_2) + \cdots +\alpha_nT(v_n)$

Since $T(v_i) \in V$, for each $i$, we can likewise write each of *those* as linear combinations of our basis elements, say:

$T(v_i) = \beta_{i1}v_1 + \cdots +\beta_{in}v_n$, so that (adding all the terms, and collecting like terms):

$T(v) = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n\left(\sum\limits_{j=1}^n \beta_{ij}\alpha_j\right)v_i$

Which says that if $M = (\beta_{ij})$, the $n \times n$ matrix with the $b_{ij}$ as entries; that expressed in the basis $B,\ T$ takes the coordinate vector $(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)^t$ to the coordinate vector $M(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)^t$-where the latter is the matrix product of the $n\times n$ matrix $M$ and the $n \times 1$ matrix for $v$.

Now the "numbers" (the $\alpha$'s and the $\beta$'s) used will generally differ depending on which generating set we use. However, once we fix a basis, this establishes a $F$-module isomorphism between $\text{Hom}_F(V,V)$ and the matrix ring $\text{Mat}_n(F)$ (it's even a ring-homomorphism if we use functional composition as our product in $\text{Hom}_F(V,V)$).

Comment: Thank you so much! everything is clear now.